# Angular UI tree content does not appear properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

Am new to angular framework. I implemented angular UI tree and it works fine but i have an alignment issue. consider the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="angular-ui-tree-master/examples/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="angular-ui-tree-master/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-ui-tree-master/dist/angular-ui-tree.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
          <div ui-tree-handle>
                 <span class="col-md-12">{{node.title}}</span>
          </div>
          <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.childlink">
            <li ng-repeat="node in node.childlink"  ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </script>
        <div ui-tree="treeOptions" class="dd">
            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data" id="tree-root">
                <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'" data-drag-delay="100"></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.tree']);
        myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.toggle = function (scope) {
                console.log('menu collapse');
                scope.toggle();
            };
            $scope.data = [
           {
               "id": "1",
               "title": "node1",
               "childlink": [
                   {
                       "id": "2",
                       "title": "node 1.1",
                       "childlink": [
                             {
                                 "id": "3",
                                 "title": "node 1.1.1",
                                 "childlink": []
                             },
                              {
                                  "id": "4",
                                  "title": "node 1.1.2",
                                  "childlink": []
                              }
                       ]
                   },
                    {
                        "id": "5",
                        "title": "node 1.2",
                        "childlink": []
                    }
               ]
           }
            ];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tired **without bootstrap**(class="col-md-12") it works fine and content aligned properly but i need to works along **with bootstrap**(class="col-md-12") **content does not aligned**
    {{node.title}}

In my project bootstrap get implemented in many places so am not able to override class col-md-12.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

//Try like that....hope it'll work fine.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeHierarchi">
        <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="item.children && item.children.length > 0" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span
                class="fa"
                ng-class="{
              'fa fa-arrow-right': !collapsed,
              'fa fa-arrow-down': collapsed
            }"></span></a>
            <input type="text"  data-ng-model="item.name" />
        </div>
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.children" ng-class="{hidden: !collapsed}">
            <li ng-repeat="item in item.children" ui-tree-node ng-include="'treeHierarchi'"></li>
        </ol>
    </script>



    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">your heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <form name="YourForm" role="form">          
                    <div class="row">
                        <div ui-tree data-nodrag id="tree-root">
                            <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="data">
                                <li ng-repeat="item in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'treeHierarchi'"></li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```